# How set all Nan values in an excel file to 0 at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

i want to display a chart between price and year (data is extracted from an csv file) there are more than 2500 data entries and some of them are NaN. My graph is all messy looking.

Ik my problem is due to those NaN values and i have already tried

```
#df.isnull(0) and df.fillna(0)/df.fillna(0, inplace = true)

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('OLX_Car_Data_CSV.csv',delimiter=',',encoding="ISO-8859-1")
#print(df.shape)

df.fillna(0)
print(df.tail(5))

a = df.Price
b = df.Year

plt.plot(a,b , color = "blue")
plt.show()
```

[image: plot preview]

Comment: Your plot is messy because it's a line plot with unordered data. You probably want `plt.bar(b, a)`, or at least `plt.plot(b, a, lw=0, marker='o')`

Comment: when i use inplace=true it shows me this error:-                                      Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'true' is not defined
  File "F:\Python\b16101156\datascience.py", line 7, in <module>
    df.fillna(0, inplace = true)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)

Comment: that isn't working either my friend. instead of a line representation i am getting a dotted one. it is the same messy thing

Comment: i wish i can show an image of my friends graph. looks neat and clean. he did something using numpy like first he set all values to 0 in a new df and then copied vales from the previous. it pretty complicated you can see it on his git https://github.com/Hamzaaasif/Visualization-and-analyzation-of-data-/blob/master/usedCarAnalyzation.py

Comment: how can i do this "Do you perhaps want to aggregate to get the average price per year, or the total price per year and then plot a single point/bar per year?" wouldn't it effect the actual representation of my data?

Comment: That is exactly what your friend is doing, because the default of `seaborn.lineplot` is to "aggregate over multiple y values at each value of x and show an estimate of the central tendency and a confidence interval for that estimate." `df.groupby('Year').Price.mean().plot()` will give you the same line as your friend, the confidence intervals come from the variance.

Comment: can kidnly explain me what to do and what i am doing wrong in "Simple words" ? cuz df.groupby('Year').Price.mean().plot() isn't working either

Answer (score 0):

`df.fillna(0)` returns a new dataframe, you need to do either: `df.fillna(0, inplace=True)` or `df=df.fillna(0)`.

Comment: Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'true' is not defined
  File "F:\Python\b16101156\datascience.py", line 7, in <module>
    df.fillna(0, inplace = true)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)

Comment: i get this error when i use inplace

Comment: `true` or `True`?

Comment: was tryping true now tried True and i am getting this:- 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Price'
  File "F:\Python\b16101156\datascience.py", line 18, in <module>
    a = df.Price
  File "C:\Python\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Python\Lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path

Comment: You use either statement, not this one `df=df.fillna(0, inplace=True)`